# Why my AngularJS + RequireJS application is not building via grunt-contrib-requirejs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, build, requirejs, grunt-contrib-requirejs

I have src of my application. I use AngularJS. I use RequireJS as module loader. I use Grunt as task runner. When I run application using src: everything is good. When I build application with Grunt, application is not working. I got no errors in console.

Main thing I noticed: my code (code of my application: app.js and files under `js/`) does not appear in output file which is set in grunt task settings. Also, I don't think there is something about AngularJS.

Main config file:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'angular' : '../components/angular/angular',
    /* etc..... */
    'jquery': '../components/jquery/dist/jquery',
    'application': './app'
  },
  shim: {
    /* etc */
    application: {
      deps: ['angular']
    },
    angular: {
      exports : 'angular'
    }
  },
  baseUrl: '/js'
});

require(['application', 'angular', 'ngRoute', 'bootstrap' /* ngRoute and bootstrap from etc :) */], function (app) {
  app.init();
});
```

My app in app.js is:

```
define([
  'require', 'angular', 'main/main', 'common/common'
], function (require) {
  'use strict';
  var angular = require('angular');
  var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'main', 'common']);
  app.init = function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
  };
  app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        ./* ... some code */

    }
  ]);

  return app;
});
```

I add main RequireJS config file at the end of `body` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="components/requirejs/require.js" data-main="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Now I have problem. I have Grunt as build system. I have this task:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  requirejs: {
    compile: {
      options: {
        baseUrl: "public/js",
        mainConfigFile: "public/js/bootstrap.js",
        name: 'bootstrap',
        out: "build/js/bootstrap.js",
        optimize: 'none'
      }
    }
  },
  // etc
```

I have no optimisation, so I get ~11k lines of code in output file.

As I said. **Main problem is: no AngularJS code and no application code in output file.**

Why? I set up mainConfigFile correctly. Problem is in RequireJS config file? But everything is okay, when I am running my app on src.

Answer (score 1):

*It would be better if you can provide the exactly error output you get. And where you got it (from browser's console or from terminal during build process)*

For now I will suggest some adjustments what could possibly help with your case.

```
angular: {
    exports : 'angular'
}
```

Here you have already export `angular.js` into <s>global</s> local variable (inside every `require` and `define` block).

And by doing `var angular = require('angular');` you are possibly asynchronously override `angular` variable inside your `app.js` module.

For `'require'` being added into `define` block, as `r.js` always reading what module got to be loaded in very first step, and then merged into single file. And this may confuse `r.js` to merging `requireJS` into itself.

Suggest this adjustment for your `app.js`:

```js
define([ // Removed 'require' because no needed , it is already global and usable anywhere
  'angular', 'main/main', 'common/common'
], function () {
  'use strict';
  // var angular = require('angular'); // This is a very common mistake. You are not going to call angular this way, requireJS difference with commonJS. 
  var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'main', 'common']);
  app.init = function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
  };
  app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        ./* ... some code */

    }
  ]);

  return app;
});
```

<s>**And last but not least**  `data-main="js/bootstrap.js"` I think it should be `js/main.js` or a typo.</s>

**EDIT** added explanations for `'require'` in `define` block, and `angular` local variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. _As I mentioned in my question: I don't get any errors about mistakes in console or anywhere_. About your code: you remove require dependency and require call, right? I will try it at the evening, but I am not sure it will help. At least I don't understand _now_ how it will help.

Comment: As I said: I have this symptom: I don't see any mentions of AngularJS or my source code in output file. Also, about bootstrap.js. I named main config file - bootstrap.js, so data-main is `js/bootstrap.js`

Comment: Understood for `js/bootstrap.js` because in your question you called it main config :) --- regarding with the adjustment, it is to avoid to override your `angular` variable. When you define `var angular = require('angular')`. I will update my answer to explain it better.

Comment: So, you just suggest something and it is not solution of my main answer? Better to post it as comment may be. Anyway, you might be correct. I will update my code anyway. I just don't understand how this will solve my main problem: no AngularJS or source code in output file.

Comment: It is **possibly a solution**, but I do not have you code in hand. Maybe problem cause else where in other modules. Since we have no error output, I cannot confirm it but only you, when you apply my suggestion/solution. (It is just matter of a way to call it)

Comment: Again. Symptom: AngularJS and source code doesn't appear in output file. How `grunt-contrib-requirejs` know about what to copy into output? Configuration set in mainConfigFile. I provided it: first block code. I set dependencies of my app: there is `jquery` and `bootstrap` (this libs appears in final output file), also I have `application` and `angular` as dependencies there. This libs not appear in output file. Why? Because the way how I include `angular` in my app.js? I don't even get `app.js` code in output. How it can fluence?

Comment: No output is possibly because you are added `'require'` into `define` dependencies. This is ok for running rawly, but when it come to `'r.js'`, it is likely you are telling `r.js` to merge `requireJS` into itself and caused the conflict. --- (Check the answer again, I updated it with better explainations)

Comment: Fine. Now really good explanation. I will try it as soon as possible. Voted up anyway. Thank you.

Comment: Well, it didn't help me. I just tried to remove deps 1 by 1 and realised, that I have problem with boostrap dependency. I renamed it to bootstrap-lib and get worked builded project. Now I have new challenge :) 1.5 mb of main js file

Comment: It is good to heard you found a solution :) --- Maybe try to use `angularAMD` with `ngload!` and some other on-demand loading for js file --- My main.js was pretty much the same weight, but after some adjustment it is 400kb+ for page initial.

Comment: I solved this. I started using uglify2 optimization. Now I have 350 kb of my project src`s, libs and r.js lib.